# Using shared memory in mod_perl environment

Tags: perl, shared-memory, mod-perl

I have a requirement wherein

1. I have to place a data structure (Perl hash) in memory, so that each HTTP process (running a Perl script) will use that hash.
2. The hash structure is around 300 MB.
3. The environment is mod_perl

I thought of creating a module to load at Apache start that creates a hash in a shared region and returns a reference to it.

Can you please comment on the behaviour, or suggest alternative solutions. Also please point to some good resources to check the examples.

Comment: Your question is far too broad although you may get useful answers. You know by now that Stack Overflow is about answering *specific* programming problems.

Comment: Ogata Tetsuji's answer below seems like a clever solution to the problem, but really, I'd have to step back and reconsider the problem.  This is a problem more commonly solved by storing the large data structure outside of the Perl process, e.g. with a database or some kind of file structure.  Even if you use a conventional SQL database, the data will quickly be moved to the OS disk cache and query times become very fast.  You might also look at in-memory datastores like Memcached, which will give competitive response times.

Answer (score 1):

If you place huge hash data on mod_perl memory,
then mod_perl parent process reads it at server startup phase.

In first, you create `Your/HugeData.pm` on `@INC` directory.

```
package Your::HugeData;

our %dictionary = (
    ....
);
```

Next, apache process reads this on startup.

```
# In apache.conf (or anywhere apache config file)
PerlModule Your::HugeData
```

Then your script can use `%Your::HugeData::dictionary` as package variable.

```
# In mod_perl handler script or ModPerl::Registry (CGI emulate) script.
use Your::HugeData;
...
my $tokyo = $Your::HugeData::dictionary{tokyo};
```

When you use prefork MPM on Linux Apache, OS prefers "Copy on Write" mechanism.
So forked child processes see parent proces'es data if you only read the data.
In other words, there may be not waste memory using.

Comment: Be wary of taking references to shared data in child processes - this equates to a 'write' on the page.
You can read a concrete example here: https://retout.co.uk/blog/2012/12/21/

Answer (score 0):

I would be thinking in terms of handing it around via [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html)  `store` it to a file, `retrieve` it at start.

If it needs to change, you'd need to use `flock` to arbitrate IO, and potentially some sort of mechanism for checking when it changed last (e.g. check mtime).